Как правильно решать капчу Cloudflare Turnstile?
На сайте используется капча Cloudflare Turnstile. На странице с этой капчей есть форма для ввода данных и кнопка, которая становится доступной после её решения. Для решения капчи я использую сервис 2captcha, который возвращает токен. Этот токен я вставляю в поля cf-turnstile-response и g-recaptcha-response. Правильно ли я всё делаю?
(фото кода страницы прикрепил)

